# Прошу помощи найти ошибку в коде

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравсвтуйте. Хочу делать динамический поиск на сайти по имени. Пол дня немог одну проблему решить, потом вроде решил, теперь опять не рабоатет) вообщем ниже я привел пример как оно должно работать. В этом коде впринцыпе все работает нормально. У меня на сайте код почти идентичен только чуть побольше он ниже. Помогите пожалуйста может я что-то упускаю но совсем не понимаю почему оно работает.
Масив приходит в сервера все нормально, я запускаю функцию для товаром без скидки и со скидкой. Они отображаются нормально. Решил использовать эту же функцию при поиске но я совсем ничего не понимаю. Оно создает *('.'+productsType+'-wrapper')* но не создает блоки с товаром к ним.
Дело в том, что такая проблема только при поиске, когда функция запускается в 
*$('input[search]').on('keyup', function(e){*
Я совсем уже не понимаю из за чего оно может лагать. Я пробовал и поиск отключать и чтобы она запускалась просто при нажатии и не вводила требования для поиска всеравно так же не создаются блоки. Точнеё создаеться 1 для второго 
*('.'+productsType+'-wrapper')* и то когда-как.
Функция для примера

```js
'use scrict';
$(function(){
let discArray = [{'name':'test1'},{'name':'test'},{'name':'test'},{'name':'test2'},{'name':'test3'}],
    normArray = [{'name':'test'},{'name':'test1'},{'name':'test'},{'name':'test4'},{'name':'test'}];
function pushProducts(productsType, productData, search){
$('#'+productsType+'-products').empty();
let productCounter = 0,
    firstWrapper = true;
for(let i=0;i<productData.length;i++){
  if(search != null && productData[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) == -1 && search != '') continue;
    if(firstWrapper || productCounter == 3){
        $('#'+productsType+'-products').append('<div class="'+productsType+'-wrapper"></div>');
        firstWrapper = false;
        if(productCounter == 3) {
            $('.'+productsType+'-wrapper').eq(this.length - 1).addClass('hide-slider-right');
            productCounter = 0;
        }
    }
    productCounter++;
    $('.'+productsType+'-wrapper').eq(this.length - 1).append(`<div class="item">Test</div>`);
}
}
$('#test').on('keyup', function(e){
        pushProducts('norm', normArray, $(this).val());
        pushProducts('disc', discArray, $(this).val());
});
pushProducts('norm', normArray, '');
pushProducts('disc', discArray, '');
});
```

```css
#disc-products, #norm-products{
background: grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.disc-wrapper{
width: 100px;
height: 100%;
background: red;
float: left;
}
.norm-wrapper{
width: 100px;
height: 100%;
background: blue;
float: left;
}
.item{
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="disc-products"></div>
<div id="norm-products"></div>
<input id="test" type="text">
```

Функция на моём сайте:

```js
    //Get Products
    var featured,
        discount;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/products.json',
        success: function(data){
            featured = JSON.parse(data.featured);
            discount = JSON.parse(data.discount);
            pushProducts('featured', featured, null);
            pushProducts('discount', discount, null);
        }
    });
    function pushProducts(productsType, productData, search){
            $('#'+productsType+'-products').empty();
            let productCounter = 0,
                firstWrapper = true;
            for(let i=0;i<productData.length;i++){
                if(search != null && productData[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) == -1 && search != '') continue;
                if(firstWrapper || productCounter == 3){
                    $('#'+productsType+'-products').append('<div class="'+productsType+'-wrapper slide-styles"></div>');
                    firstWrapper = false;
                    if(productCounter == 3) {
                        $('.'+productsType+'-wrapper').eq(this.length - 1).addClass('hide-slider-right');
                        productCounter = 0;
                    }
                }
                productCounter++;
                $('.'+productsType+'-wrapper').eq(this.length - 1).append(`<div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <div class="footwear-item">
                                                    <div class="footwear-image background-for-images" style="background-image: url(css/images/`+productsType+`-products/`+productData[i].img+`)"></div>
                                                    <div class="footwear-panel">
                                                        <p class="foonwear-name pt16">`+productData[i].name+`</p>
                                                        <div class="footwear-price pt24">`+productData[i].price+`$</div>
                                                        <button class="buy">BUY NOW</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    </div>`);
                if(productsType == 'discount') $('#discount-products .footwear-image').eq(i).append('<div class="disc-mark"></div>');
            }
    }
    //Search
    $('input[search]').on('keyup', function(e){
        if($(this).val() == '') $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(css/images/search-Icon.png)'});
        else $(this).css({'background-image': 'none'});
        
        pushProducts('featured', featured, '');
        pushProducts('discount', discount, '');
    });
```

На скриншоте показываю что при вводе в поле поиска вот вроде как создаеются 2 контейнера *dispount-wrapper* как и должно быть(всего 4 товара на каждый из видов на 1 контейнер не больше 3 товаров), но первый пустой, во втором 1 товар как и должен быть по счету(правда почему-то без марки скидки).
[image: Скриншот при вводе первой буквы в поиск]
а вот как сайт выглядит когда только заходишь на него 
[image: При входе]

И если поле потом делаю пустым так-же ничего.

Comment: Отладку уже использовал?

Comment: нет. Как её использовать?

Comment: читаем и вникаем https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome